# Coherent absorption of light in photosynthesis

Tags: visible-light

I am reading [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6233348/) article about vibronic coherence in photosynthesis right now, and I came across the following line about initial photon absorption in Photosystem II:

> For a single cell, only one solar photon is likely to impinge on the cell during the timescale of energy transfer of a single excitation. The coherence volume of the photon is much larger than cellular dimensions, meaning that the photon can interact with all suitable chromophores in a single cell.

This confused me quite a bit, because the size of the average plant cell is on the order of 10 um or so, while the wavelengths of light that power photosynthesis have wavelength around 500 nm. So how is it possible that this kind of light can interact with every chromophore in the cell at once?

Comment: Sounds like a physics question to me. Do you know what the cohesion volume of a photon means? I don’t, but a physicist might.  Whether you will get two physicists to agree is another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coherence volumes are explained in [this abstract](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.5032737), though I don't think I can read more than the abstract of that paper to say for sure.

It seems that the coherence volume is the quantum representation of the size of a photon, which is in practice a more relevant value than the wavelength due to the distribution of possible quantum positions the photon is actually occupying.

This is illuminated a little bit by the next bit after your quote, which answers a question I had about how one photon can excite all the chromophores:

> From a quantum mechanical perspective, the photon will initially excite all resonant chromophores within the coherence volume in a superposition of states; however, this collective excitation will decay on femtosecond time scale resulting in the excitation being localised to a single protein system.